# How can I set Triggered Send Priority through REST API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email

I have some time sensitive emails I am triggering through the REST API messageDefinitionSends resource. however, I have noticed they linger around in the queue for a while before sending. I saw with the SOAP API you can set the priority. Is there a way to do that through the REST API or somewhere else in the interaction or email?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So when you pay for priority sends, and it is activated in your account, it auto-magically shows up in the Triggered Send definition UI.  Now that wasn't so difficult was it? :)

Comment: Is this actually supposed to be an answer?

Comment: you are correct...the answer is you can't. Instead you set it in the UI of the triggered send, and then all messages triggered through the API to that specific triggered send is at that priority

Answer (score 0):

Trigger Priority is an additional per-email charge that has to be provisioned.  You'll need to contact your SFMC rep.

Reference: [Triggered Emails Guide -> Priority](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/triggered_emails/triggered_emails_guide/#section_9)